# Where is the cookie stored that session_start() uses?

Tags: php, session, cookies

Where can I find the cookie that session_start uses?

Comment: It should be in the same place as all the other cookies your browser stores...

Comment: `print_r($_COOKIE);`, Firefox uses `cookie.sqlite` (as does Chrome), see also Preferences > Privacy > individual cookies.

Comment: I highly doubt this has something to do with the cookies. I would take a hard look at your code first...

Comment: @mario - so I would have to use a sql client to pull just a single id from a sql table..as per below...that is all that is contained on the client side?

Comment: Leave the browser cookie store alone. It's none of your business. There is a menu entry for looking at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For standard PHP sessions with default settings, you can get the cookie key/value with:

```
 session_name() -> session cookie's KEY
 session_id() -> session cookie's VALUE
```

However, note that whatever you write to $_SESSION is **NOT** stored in the cookie itself. The session cookie contains ONLY the session ID value. The data your write in $_SESSION is stored on the server - usually in a file, unless you've rolled your own session handlers and are storing it in a different manner.

Comment: Because a session cookie by itself is innocent. But when that session cookie is served up by a 3rd party advertising network, that one cookie can track your movements across ANY sites you visit that use the same ad network.